What is the Capture request endpoint for cybersource, I am using secureacceptance API?
I am new to payment integration and find myself lost in the developer integration guide, it seems to be too much info, where as I am only looking for REST APIs to for capture, refund etc.
Ref: https://developer.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API/Secure_Acceptance_Checkout_API.pdf
I have already done the tokenization and I can see my token is created from CS dashboard.

The endpoint urls and the supported transaction types are on pages 48-52 of the pdf you linked. For capture, you would use the Process Transaction Endpoints on page 51. Keep in mind you need to set up and activate your Secure Acceptance Profile first.

Thanks. Finally I figured out it was easy after I have my account setup and had access to Cybersource dashboard
